# Variables not being detected in blackjack program in Python

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, syntax, blackjack

I wrote the following program to play blackjack with the user, but whenever a player gets a Jack, Queen, or King, the if statements in the total_value function do not detect them. What should I do to fix this? Also, do you have any general pointers to clean up my code or make my syntax better?

```
import random
from random import randint

class deck():
    """This class holds the deck information"""
    clubs = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
    spades = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
    hearts = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
    diamonds = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
    suites = ["clubs", "spades", "hearts", "diamonds"]

    def drawcard(self):
        #This method removes a card from the deck and returns it.
        #Do not draw cards when there are none left.
        if self.suites:
            suite = random.choice(self.suites)
            suite_number = randint(0, len(self.suites) - 1)
            if suite == "clubs":
                card = (self.clubs).pop(randint(0, len(self.clubs) - 1))
                if not self.clubs:
                    (self.suites).remove("clubs")
            elif suite == "spades":
                card = (self.spades).pop(randint(0, len(self.spades) - 1))
                if not self.spades:
                    (self.suites).remove("spades")
            elif suite == "hearts":
                card = (self.hearts).pop(randint(0, len(self.hearts) - 1))
                if not self.hearts:
                    (self.suites).remove("hearts")
            elif suite == "diamonds":
                card = (self.diamonds).pop(randint(0, len(self.diamonds) - 1))
                if not self.diamonds:
                    (self.suites).remove("diamonds")
            return card, suite
        else:
            return "OUT", "CARDS ERROR"

def total_value(hand):
    #This function returns the current total value of a player's hand.
    #For example, ["A", "K"] would return 21.
    value = 0
    aces = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == "A":
            aces = aces + 1
        elif card == "J":
            value == value + 10
        elif card == "Q":
            value == value + 10
        elif card == "K":
            value == value + 10
        else:
            value = value + card
    if aces == 1:
        if value <= 10:
            value = value + 11
        elif value > 10:
            value = value + 1
    elif aces == 2:
        if value <= 9:
            value = value + 12
        elif value > 9:
            value = value + 2
    elif aces == 3:
        if value <= 8:
            value = value + 13
        elif value > 8:
            value = value + 3
    elif aces == 4:
        if value <= 7:
            value = value + 14
        elif value > 7:
            value = value + 4
    return value

new_deck = deck()
player_hand = [ ]
card1 = new_deck.drawcard()
card2 = new_deck.drawcard()
print "You have drawn a " + str(card1[0]) + " of " + card1[1] + " and a " + str(card2[0]) + " of " + card2[1] + "!"
player_hand.append(card1[0])
player_hand.append(card2[0])

dealer_hand = [ ]
card3 = new_deck.drawcard()
card4 = new_deck.drawcard()
dealer_hand.append(card3[0])
dealer_hand.append(card4[0])

gameover = False
win = False
dealer_finished = False
player_finished = False
while not gameover:
    while dealer_finished == False:
        if total_value(dealer_hand) < 17:
            card = new_deck.drawcard()
            dealer_hand.append(card[0])
        elif total_value(dealer_hand) >= 17:
            dealer_finished = True
    if total_value(dealer_hand) > 21:
        print "Dealer Busts!"
        win = True
        gameover = True
        break
    while player_finished == False:
        choice = raw_input("Hit or Stay? ")
        choice.capitalize()
        if choice == "Hit":
            card = new_deck.drawcard()
            player_hand.append(card[0])
            print "You drew a", card[0], "of " + card[1]
            if total_value(player_hand) > 21:
                player_finished = True
                break
        elif choice == "Stay":
            player_finished = True
            gameover = True
            break
        else:
            print "Invalid Option"
    if total_value(player_hand) > 21:
        win == False
        gameover == True
        break
    gameover == True

if win == True:
    print "Congratulations!"
else:
    print total_value(player_hand), total_value(dealer_hand)
    if total_value(player_hand) > 21:
        print "You bust!"
    elif total_value(dealer_hand) > total_value(player_hand):
        print "The dealer had", str(total_value(dealer_hand)), "but you only had", str(total_value(player_hand)) + "."
        print "You lose!"
    elif total_value(dealer_hand) == total_value(player_hand):
        print "You tie the dealer with", total_value(dealer_hand)
    elif total_value(dealer_hand) < total_value(player_hand):
        print "The dealer had", str(total_value(dealer_hand)), "and you had", str(total_value(player_hand)) + ", so you win!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have double-equals signs for the `J`, `Q`, and `K` cases:

```
    if card == "A":
        aces = aces + 1
    elif card == "J":
        value == value + 10    #xxx
    elif card == "Q":
        value == value + 10    #xxx
    elif card == "K":
        value == value + 10    #xxx
    else:
        value = value + card
```

All this does is check whether `value` is `value + 10` and evaluate to `True` or `False`. You want to assign the value:

```
    if card == "A":
        aces = aces + 1
    elif card == "J":
        value = value + 10
    elif card == "Q":
        value = value + 10
    elif card == "K":
        value = value + 10
    else:
        value = value + card
```

or better yet:

```
    if card == "A":
        aces = aces + 1
    elif card == "J":
        value += 10
    elif card == "Q":
        value += 10
    elif card == "K":
        value += 10
    else:
        value += card
```